# Pegar valores de um vetor e usar em uma função

Tags: array, c++, matemática

Tenho um vetor `XC[i]` onde gero com o código abaixo:

```
for(i = 0;i<N_Volumes;i++){
        double XC[i];       
        XC[i] = (xC0+=delta_x)-1.0; 
        printf ("XC[%d]= %f\n", i, XC[i])};
```

Quero pegar esses valores de `XC[i]` e usar na função `double Sp= XC[i]*XC[i]`

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Comece corrigindo a sintaxe de seus comandos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar como parâmetro na função.
Exemplo

```
void funcaoVetor(int vetor[]) {
 //código da função aqui
}
//chamada da função
funcaoVetor(vetor[50]);
```

Entretanto tem diferença nas passagens, você pode passar por parâmetro podendo alterar os valores deste vetor ou como referencia em que a alteração ocorre apenas dentro da função, mas não muda o valor da variável.
Mas pelo que você citou creio que seja a passagem em parâmetro então é só fazer como qualquer variável.